# Color bottom of the page starting from footnote

Tags: footnotes, boxes

Is this a realistic request?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    paperwidth=32pc,%
    paperheight=48pc,%
    margin=5pc,%
]{geometry}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

This is a sentence.\footnote{This is a footnote.}

\end{document}
```

Is it possible to make the bottom section of the page colored **if there is footnote and with respect footnote size**?

[image]

If not, or if it is too much of a hack, is it possible to insert a custom box at the bottom of the page so as to achieve the desired effect? (I put the black border just to make the page more visible.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like this (it can need a few compilation to set down). It should work also will split footnotes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}
\usepackage[
    paperwidth=32pc,%
    paperheight=48pc,%
    margin=5pc,%
]{geometry}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\footnoterule{%
  \kern-3\p@
  \pgfmark{fn-\thepage}\hrule\@width.4\columnwidth
  \kern2.6\p@}
\begin{document}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
\iftikzmark{fn-\thepage}{\tikz[overlay,remember picture]\fill[blue!50!white]($({pic cs:fn-\thepage} -| {current page.west})+(0,2pt)$) rectangle (current page.south east);}{}}

  This is a sentence.\lipsum[2-3]\footnote{This is a footnote.\lipsum[1-4]}

  \lipsum[1-4] \lipsum[1-4]
   \footnote{this is a footnote} \footnote{footnote}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. How can I remove the footnote rule? `\renewcommand*\footnoterule{}` works but disables your solution. I tried to change the color of the rule to the fill color, but that changed font color also.

Comment: Set the width of the hrule to zero `\hrule\@width 0pt`.